# How to make ImageView larger than screen width and scroll with Animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I'm looking for some thing that make my `ImageView` width larger than screen width.

After scrolling the image using animation like this :

```
AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);
        animationSet.setFillAfter(true);
        TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(-1
                * (curruntFragment * 40),
                -1 * ((curruntFragment + 1) * 40), 0, 0);

        translateAnimation.setStartOffset(400);
        translateAnimation.setDuration(200);
        translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

        animationSet.addAnimation(translateAnimation);
        imgBackground.setAnimation(animationSet);
        imgBackground.startAnimation(animationSet);
```

it will not cut out like this image

[image]

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: I'm trying to make some animation that appear like 

"linkedIn application" at start :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.linkedin.android

Comment: I mean this version not the latest one 
https://ws.cubbyusercontent.com/p/_8ebd04e301e844b492c99e9d5480bbdf/LinkedIn_3.2.apk/602538286

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your question mean "Full-Screen "Immersive Mode" on Android Without Rooting" If it is, then this is how to do it:

**==> Configuring Immersive Mode**

Open up GMD Immersive to access the settings, then go to the General subsection and enable Notification. You can decide whether you want an invisible icon for the app's pending notification in the status bar, as well as whether you want the app to start on boot and remain active in the lock screen.

In the Trigger subsection, you can make changes to the sensitivity and positioning of the trigger that is shown at the bottom of your screen to recall the status and nav bars. You can also set Immersive Mode on a per-app basis through the Applications subsection, although that is a PRO feature.

**==> Using Immersive Mode**

Whether you're on your home screen or in an application, pull down your notification panel to choose which immersive screen you want to enable. You have the choice of either keeping both bars active, removing the nav bar only, or removing both the nav and status bars.

With both removed, those bold black borders on your screen will disappear, expanding your viewable area. It's a great way to enhance your reading activity and internet browsing on your device. To expose the nav bar again, just tap or swipe the red trigger area along the bottom. Beware that your keyboard may not work in Immersive Mode, which is why having the toggle in the notification shade is so handy. You can also choose to restore navigation bar whenever you need to use keyboard!

There are other options here: http://www.trendymediablog.com/2014/09/how-to-get-full-screen-immersive-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Info on different scaletypes: http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2014/01/imageview-scaletypes.html

Comment: it doesn't work for me for some more explanation :
I'm wont to have an image that have more than screen width and after scrolling it with the animation it doesn't cut out like image it will display some of the out screen of this image